# Sorting list by an object field missing in some objects in the list

Tags: java, sorting, null, comparator

I need to display a list of account objects and sorting on one of the account object fields (all string type). However, some account fields value is `null` so NOT showing in the `JSON`. It gives me a `null pointer exception` when sorting on those missing field. How can I have the `Comparator` ignore the missing field during sorting ?

I tried `Comparator.comparing()` but it only works on the common field (existing in all account object). If I tried to sort on the field missing in one of the account objects. `NullPointerExceptio`n happens. Of course, if I tried to force all fields show up with those field as empty string value ("") then it works as normal but it does not look good since it might be too many of those fields.

Accounts definition

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String type;    
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String accountNumber;
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String accountStatus;
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String accountValue;
    ....
```

Sort following list - only type and accountNumber are common

```
"accounts": [
 {
  "type": "type1",
  "accountNumber": "1816227",
  "accountStatus": "cancelled",
 },
 {
  "type": "type2",
  "accountNumber": "2816218",
  "accountValue": "19438.60",

 },
 {
  "type": "type3",
  "accountNumber": "2209890",
  "accountStatus": "inactive",
  "accountValue": "4343.410",
 }
```

---

```
  if (sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {         
   accountComparator = Comparator.comparing(Accounts::getType);
  }else if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("accountNumber")) {
   accountComparator = Comparator.comparing(Accounts::getAccountNumber);
  }else if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("accountStatus")) {
   accountComparator = Comparator.comparing(Accounts::getAccountStatus);
  }else if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("accountValue")) {    
  accountComparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(acc -> 
    Double.valueOf(acc.getAccountValue()));
   }
   ......
```

`Nullpointer exception` on following line when `Sort` on `accountStatus` and 
 `accountValue` which are missing in one of the accounts.
    `totalAcctList.sort(accountComparator.reversed());`

As mentioned, if I make all accounts showing `accountStatus` and 
 `accountValue` such as "accountStatus":"" and `"accountValue":"0.0"` then it 
 works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could decide to have all the `null`s at the beginning or the end of the list, and use [`Comparator.nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) or [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) respectively:

```
else if (sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("accountStatus")) {
   accountComparator = 
       Comparator.comparing(Accounts::getAccountStatus, 
                            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
}
```

**EDIT:**

For `accountValue` you could take a similar approach, although since primitive `double`s can not be `null`, you'll have to handle them first, before attempting to parse:

```
else if (sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("accountValue")) {    
  accountComparator = 
      Comparator.comparing((Account a) -> a.getAccountValue() == null)
                .thenComparingDouble((Account a) -> 
                                     Double.parseDouble(a.getAccountValue()));
}
```

Comment: Mureinik, thanks for the great comments. However, it appears that the Comparator.comparingDouble() for sorting on accountValue only have one parameter in the signature.

Comment: @user1747980 for doubles, you'll need a slightly different (less elegant) technique. See my edited answer.

Comment: "primitive doubles can be null" - you need to fix this text

Comment: @SharonBenAsher yup, missed the all important "not" there. Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik and Sharon for further improvement of the answer. Mureinik, so a.getAccountValue() == null should be a.getAccountValue() != null , right ?

Comment: @user1747980 `a.getAccountValue() == null ` will return false for objects with a proepr value, and true for objects with a null value. Since `Boolean`s natural order is false before true, this will create a comparator where objects with a null value are moved to the end of the list. You could of course decide you want them in the begining of the list by inverting the condition - up to you.